# How to place all selected vertices is same position in UV map?

Tags: uv, vertices, uv-image-editor

Given the following scenario, how could I quickly and easily place all of the selected vertices from two overlapping islands in the same position?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select them and scale them to 0.

- Select the two vertices, then press <kbd>s</kbd>, then <kbd>0</kbd>.

Because they are just **points** in space, this *will not* effect the ***verts***, but *it will* put them in the **same place**, because the ***vector*** "connecting" them will be scaled to *zero*.

---

There is a **better** method however.

- Select an island.
- Set "snapping" mode to vertices.
- Grab (<kbd>g</kbd>) and hold <kbd>ctrl</kbd> to snap.
- Move all islands to the same location.

[image]

- **Tip**; UV select mode to "islands".

[image]

---

You can do something similar to multiple vertices at once by:

- Moving them to relatively the same position. (<kbd>l</kbd> and <kbd>g</kbd>).
- Select all (<kbd>a</kbd>).
- Open the specials menu (<kbd>w</kbd>).
- Choose *"Remove Doubles UV"*

[image]

---

### If you have **LOTS** of islands!

As a final workaround method, if you have LOTS of islands, you can use this scaling hack. It is not technically a "good" method, but it works. The goal of this method is to scale everything down to one point, then blow it back up. To be able to blow it back up, we need to leave some geometric data, so we can't actually scale to 0.

- Select all (<kbd>a</kbd>).
- Select **"Median Point"** from the *Rotation/Scaling Pivot* menu.
- Scale to a very small number (<kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>0.0001</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
- Select **"Individual Origins"** from the *Rotation/Scaling Pivot* menu.
- Scale the islands back to their original size (<kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>10000</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

The islands should now all have approximately the same origin. You can move them to your desired location.

Comment: If i have 100 island it will take time to select and position is there any alternate or one click

Comment: Okay, I found a way, although it's not really a "good" way. I will update the answer and it will be the last option.

Comment: Using that method I have had success, however, it has seemed to not work some times. I'm not sure why, but just try again if it fails. I hope it helps you. :)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[Snap] feature with UV Island Selection Mode may eliminate the need for fine movements of UV islands by the Blender User.

Image Editor showing UV of a cube with seams unwrapped.  Selection Mode is Island as indicated by the arrow.  One island is already moved.  New island selected. UV Cursor is set in the upper left hand corner.  You may set the cursor in a place that suits you and keep that location.

Press [Shift-S].
Choice .. Selection to Cursor (Offset)

will move the island to the cursor.  My islands have same dimensions. It looks like yours do too. Above.

[image]

Island is moved. Above.

[image]

All islands moved. The are on top of each other. Above.

[image]

Islands are Box Selected and moved to final locations.  This movement can happen first or be eliminated.  The pivot point may allow an improvement.

[image]

As an improvement.  The first snap of the cursor could have been the first island.  Potentially eliminating the last step above.  The cursor is more difficult to see in this image and is inside the UV island next to the arrow.